# Removing item from a list once chosen Dropdown Googlesheets Script

Tags: list, google-apps-script, google-sheets, drop-down-menu

I want to Remove an item from a list once chosen in the dropdown and then the next dropdown won't have that item anymore. I've already made something manually but it takes super long and is not really ideal because you would need to go down in order otherwise it gets all mixed up.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o3J1ZXzxQL11pdN1FDOQZ7YXbSib6A8KwkxBzO5bSM0/edit?usp=sharing

I've made 3 tabs one where I explain what I want and the other were I made it manually so you have an idea on how it works. But remember the manually one you need to go down in order. I want for it to look at a range so it doesn't matter which dropdown I choose for it to get removed from the list.

If it isn't possible to do it by range then like the same way as manually but then in script form would be a great help as well.

Here is what I tried but I'm really new with scripting so I might not even be close:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Dropdown');
 //get's the value in range A1 ( the firstdropdown value )
  var firstDrop = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
  //get's the value in range A3 ( the seconddropdown value )
  var secondDrop = ss.getRange("A3").getValue();
  //get the list ( I don't want to put the list in here sincec I'll be
//working with entries from google forms. so the list will be changing)
  var list = ss.getRange("H1:H5").getValues();
  
  if(firstDrop == list){
    var newlist = (list-firstDrop);
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use standard validation to do this just set it up for ranges that are significantly bigger than you need it won’t use blanks it’ll leave them out then all you have to do is go in and grab the data on the range find out the index of the one you want to emove remove it with splice and then use set values to paste them back in the range seems pretty simple to me

Comment: I'm not that experienced yet so no way close to simple to me :( I don't understand everything you are talking about but thank you for your time on answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you - I think it gives you the result you want, but its appearance isn't ideal.  I've placed it into your sheet, in the last tab.  I believe that this is the same approach as Mateo's earlier answer, but down with a formula instead of code.

```
=SORT(FILTER(B2:B;NOT(COUNTIF(A2:A;B2:B))))
```

where A is the column where you are entering data, and B has your list of valid names/words.

I use this formula to filter the list of words/names that show in each dropdown list.  It starts with the original list, and excludes any that have already been selected.  The data validation for your cells points to the filtered list, not the original list.

The drawback is that once you select a word/name, it is no longer eligible for the dropdown cells, so even the cell where it has already been applied shows it as an invalid entry, with a little red triangle.  The benefit of a working solution may outweigh this though.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and yes this works perfectly. I have no idea how I didn't think of this. Was there writing super difficult lines of code. And no the little triangle in the corner is no problem at all. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should look like this:

```js
function availableSlots(){
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl('URL_OF_YOUR_FORM'); // TODO add your form url
  // need to read what slots are available
  var slots = SpreadsheetApp
                .getActiveSpreadsheet()
                .getRange("slots!A2:C10")
                .getValues(); // TODO make sure getRange matches your quota range
  var choice = [];
  // loop through our available slots
  for (s in slots){
    // test if slot still available
    if (slots[s][0] != "" && slots[s][2] > 0){ 
      choice.push(slots[s][0]); // if so we add to temp array
    }
  }
  var formItems = form.getItems(FormApp.ItemType.LIST); // our form list items
  // TODO assumption that first select list is the one you want to change  
  // change formItems[n] if you have more than one select list
  // and we just rewrite all the options to ones that are free
  formItems[0].asListItem().setChoiceValues(choice); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I think you understand it wrong with the form bit. I don't want to change anything in the form. So there is no need to get my form URL. everything will happen through the sheets itself. So everything is really just happening in 1 tab. The code looks on a range where the dropdowns will be standing and then has to see if it matches the list. if it does remove from the list and give a new list and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As I was not sure which dropdown menus you wanted to use I have created a sample sheet with your requirements (photo attached below). In order to reduce the list of items in function of the output of the rest of the dropdowns I have used on [onEdit()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger to check for any changes in these dropdowns and in function of these cell values remove the required items from the list.

The following piece of code has self explanatory comments that address how I have implemented this:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Share your Ideas here :)');

  // Get list from range. Flat will make the 2D array returned by getVaues() into a 1D array
  var list = sheet.getRange("E1:E5").getValues().flat();

  // Get values from the dropdowns
  var a = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var b = sheet.getRange("B1");
  var c = sheet.getRange("C1");

  // Check if any of the values in the dropdowns match the list and if so remove them from
  // the list 
  var index = list.indexOf(a.getValue()); if(index != -1){list.splice(index,1);}
  index = list.indexOf(b.getValue()); if(index != -1){list.splice(index,1);}
  index = list.indexOf(c.getValue()); if(index != -1){list.splice(index,1);}

// Create the data validation rule with the filtered list 
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();

// Create/update the dropdowns with the right filtered list
  a.setDataValidation(rule); 
  b.setDataValidation(rule); 
  c.setDataValidation(rule); 
}
```

[image]

#### References

- [Data Validation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation)
- [requireValueInList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues)

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. Sorry for not being able to respond earlier. Had it super busy at work. I've tried it out and I'm having problems with the flat() , it doesn't want to run the script if I let flat in the line. You got any idea why?